# Is there a better way to do configSections in VS 2010 Beta2?

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I noticed in the default web.config files for the latest release of MVC distributed with VS 2010 Beta 2 that many of the sections are now missing.

With a little research I found [ScottGu's article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/08/25/clean-web-config-files-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) explaining why this was.

My question is is there a new way to load namespaces in this release of .net and should we no longer be utilizing the "configSections" within the web.config?  Just to note it does still work to place a configSection in the web.confg.

Sample from the Unity web.config  Eg:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration"/>
</configSections>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web.config is still the correct place and should work just as before - its just easier now with all the 'clutter' removed.